# Remove duplicates values in aggregation with limit in Mongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have a dataset (an example):

```
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [151.5162, -9.44365]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad70f71f2119236741ffb39'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'592795', u'STATUS': u'0', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 18:52:00.000', u'MMSI': u'636015725'}}

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [119.0369, -0.3608933]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad70f71f2119236741ffb0d'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'592557', u'STATUS': u'0', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 18:49:00.000', u'MMSI': u'636092156'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [158.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad85e210b2d50e1174f5d29'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'15',   u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [158.2707, -0.8142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad85e2c0b2d50e1174f5d2a'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'15', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000',u'MMSI': u'503551000'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad878c05b66f42caf578c45'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000' }} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad878c45b66f42caf578c46'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10',  u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}
```

I want to fetch 2 random records but keep the records with the same MMSI. To be more specific, as you can see the last four records have the same MMSI. If I want to fetch 2 random records I want to return:

```
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [119.0369, -0.3608933]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad70f71f2119236741ffb0d'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'592557', u'STATUS': u'0', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 18:49:00.000', u'MMSI': u'636092156'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [158.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad85e210b2d50e1174f5d29'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'15',   u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [158.2707, -0.8142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad85e2c0b2d50e1174f5d2a'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'15', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000',MMSI': u'503551000'}} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad878c05b66f42caf578c45'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000' }} 

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'_id': ObjectId('5ad878c45b66f42caf578c46'), u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10',  u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000', u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}
```

The first with MMSI = 636092156 and the second with MMSI =503551000 (4 records).

In SQL I want something like:

```
select from table where MMSI in (select distinct(MMSI) from table limit 2));
```

So far I have the query:

```
getlimitShips = db.samplecol.aggregate([{"$lookup":{"from":"samplecol", "localField":"properties.MMSI", "foreignField":"properties.MMSI", "as":"ff"}},{ "$limit" : 97},{ "$project": {"_id":0, "ff.properties.POS_ID":0,"ff.properties.STATUS":0, "ff.properties.TIMESTAMP":0])

count_lim = 0
for limS in getlimitShips:
    print "SHIP:", limS["properties"]["MMSI"],"\n"
    count_lim = count_lim +1
    print "Record",count_lim,": ", limS,"\n"
```

that return:

> ...
>
> ...
>
> SHIP: 503551000
>
> Record 97 :  {u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates':
>   [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties':
>   {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10', u'MMSI': u'503551000',
>   u'COURSE': u'12', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000'}, 
>   u'ff': [{u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [141.8705, -12.67311]},
>   u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry':
>   {u'coordinates': [158.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [158.2707,
>   -0.8142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}]}
>
> SHIP: 503551000
>
> Record 104 :  {u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates':
>   [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties':
>   {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10', u'MMSI': u'503551000',
>   u'COURSE': u'10', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000'}, u'ff':
>   [{u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [141.8705, -12.67311]}, u'properties':
>   {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [158.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [158.2707, -0.8142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}]}
>
> SHIP: 503551000
>
> Record 105 :  {u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates':
>   [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties':
>   {u'POS_ID': u'132856', u'STATUS': u'10', u'MMSI': u'503551000',
>   u'COURSE': u'4', u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:04:00.000'}, u'ff':
>   [{u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [141.8705, -12.67311]}, u'properties':
>   {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [158.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [158.2707, -0.8142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707,
>   -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI': u'503551000'}}, {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [157.1707, -0.9142034]}, u'properties': {u'MMSI':
>   u'503551000'}}]}

As you can see the query returns the same ship with the aggregation result as many times as the records are in mongo. DO anyone how to remove the duplicates in query and return the aggregation result one time?

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself here. You say you want "distinct" but then you say *" ... but keep the records with the same MMSI ... "*. So which one is it really? Also what things need to be "distinct"? Is it the source or within the joined data? If the issue is the data with the same coordinates, then why are there multiple entries with the same coordinates in the first place? Really could use some more explanation and clarity.

Comment: I want to keep lets say 2 records. But if I have a record with the same MMSI I want to keep both records as one. I want the joined data to be distinct. The join query as you can see returns for the same MMSI again the values.